# ios: cache images in the application folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, caching, uiimage

I am working on an Iphone application.

The idea of the application is to allow the user to download a picture and to save it on his phone. and he can later open it. (Normal caching system)

What I am doing now is I get the UIIamge from the server and then I save it on the phone using:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum
```

And then I use the `imagePickerController` to allow the user to load the image.

My question is:

Is there a way I can save the image in the application folder? The idea is that I don't want to allow the user to delete the image from outside the application(I have a "clear images" button). Is there a place I can cache the images other than the Photo library? maybe in the application bundle or folder?

Thank you

Comment: try saving it in `NSDocumentsDirectory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either of the following methods to save the UIImage into your app's document directory

```
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, JPEG_COMPRESSION_QUALITY) 
          writeToFile:photoPath atomically:YES];
```

or

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:photoPath atomically:YES];
```